# Query fetch returning 'Array'

Tags: php

Here is my code. I am fairly new to PHP and mySQL. I'm having a hard time figuring out why my fetch is returning the string "Array". Also, is there a better way to write all of the echo statements? What's proper php coding rules?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($question))
{
$answerID = $row['intQAID'];
$getAnswer = mysql_query("SELECT cBody FROM tblQA WHERE intResponseID = $answerID AND intPosterID = '17'");
$answerBody = mysql_fetch_array($getAnswer);
echo "<tr class='forum'>";
echo "<td class='forum'>" . $row['intQAID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='forum'>" . substr($row['cBody'], 0, 150) . "</td>";
echo "<td class='forum'>" . $row['cCategory'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='forum'>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='forum'>" . $row['post_time'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr class='forum'>";
echo "<td class='forum'></td>";
echo "<td class='forum'>$answerBody</td>";
echo "<td class='forum'></td>";
echo "<td class='forum'></td>";
echo "<td class='forum'></td>";
}
echo "</table></div></div>";
```

Comment: the $answerBody is returning 'Array'

Answer (score 0):

It is returning `Array` because `mysql_fetch_array` is supposed to return an array. This is specified in [the documentation](http://uk.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) and the name of the function!

Because it returns an array, it will still return one even if that array only has one item in it.

Comment: It still returns "Array" when I use mysql_fetch_row as well

Comment: Again with the [documentation](http://uk3.php.net/mysql_fetch_row): "Returns a numerical array that corresponds to the fetched row"

Comment: Get the data you want *out of the array* instead of trying to get a plain string back from the database (because you won't get a plain string back from the database).

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.  The mysql_fetch_array returns an array by default.  If you try echo an array PHP outputs "Array".  There are a lot of good examples in the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) on the command.

The [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)  format is great for echoing large blocks.  Alternatively you could end your php block and just start it again when needed (which is probably what I would do in this situation).

```
<?php
   // lots of PHP statements
?>
   <table>
    ....
    <td><?php echo $variable; ?></td>
    ....
<?php
  // resume php
?>
```

Some people use [short tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php) in their code for echo.  I personally don't although it's a matter of personal preference.  The new versions of PHP have them enabled by default but older server installations may not support them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php  
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT cBody FROM tblQA WHERE intResponseID = $answerID AND intPosterID = '17'");

      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)):
 ?>
 <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['field_name']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['field_name']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['field_name']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['field_name']; ?></td>
     <!-- and so on -->
 </tr>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
```